# Angular Material ng-view stretch div min-height css 100% on safari

Tags: css, angularjs, safari, footer, angular-material

I have a problem with a simple container div not stretching to min-height:100% in my angular material project.

I have created a codepen here: 
  [Codepen](http://codepen.io/derdani/pen/VaXyor)

The problem is that I have varying amounts of content within the content-holding div (in original project **ng-view**) and therefore need to have a `min-height` of `100%-footerHeight-headerHeight` to fill the full screen and have a sticky footer at the bottom.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Maybe I wasn't clear enough: I want the footer always to be displayed below the content and in case of very few content it should stick to the bottom. So letting the content-holding div fill up using: min-height: calc(100%-footerHeight-headerHeight) of the height is the idea.

EDIT 2:

I got it working for firefox and chrome with the answers I got here. Unfortunately with the new approach I still face the same problem in safari. Here's a new 
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/derdani/pen/QNmRPy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution (works for all browsers including mobile!) which seems absolutely reasonable and simple. I have the following html structure and css:

html:

```
<div id='nav'></div>
<md-content scroll flex layout='column'>
<div id='content' ng-view flex>
</div>
<div id='footer'>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
</md-content>
```

css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#nav {
  z-index: 2;
}
#content {
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/louiealmeda/pen/YqaeoB?editors=1100)
You should use `flex`

[image]

css

```
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

in your html, I removed all styling of height and basically arrived with this structure

```
<body>
   <md-toolbar></md-toolbar>
   <div flex>your contents here</div>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

angular material have a directive attribute `flex` which makes the applied element to `flex-grow: 1` which basically takes up all the remaining space after its siblings height are placed

more info about [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

The way you presented the problem is great, keep it up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer you got exactly what's my problem. However, when I use your approach in my angular-material project and load contents dynamically (ajax) the footer is placed at the bottom of the screen (100% size) while the content is longer than the screen. Also, you might have noticed the div above the content-holding div with ng-if="" ... for some pages I need a screen-filling (100%) picture above the contents. When I use height:100% there (<div ng-if="true" style="height:100%; background-color:blue;"></div>), the picture is not shown. What is the correct flexing approach here?

Comment: I feel like the angular material html,body{height:100%; position:relative;} is the problem..

Comment: I'll create a simpler demo for you, to avoid too much noise from the elements that is not related

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix most views with your approach. Now I'm facing issues as safari or webkit in general doesn't take the flex property of body. With firefox and chrome everything looks good! Do you have an idea what causes this issue?

Comment: btw you can reproduce it with your codepen, just use safari and the body { display:flex; ..} is not used anymore. I've tried adding body{
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
} without any results

Comment: Sorry, I don't have safari. Here's what you can try: the body in the dev tools, check which `display` style is applied to it and from where

Comment: Too bad! Tried that already, it says it took the flex attribute but still the footer is not at the bottom ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your style sheet:

```
#footer {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Footer will stick at the bottom. Help this hope.

Comment: sorry maybe I wasn't clear: I want the footer always to be displayed below the content and in case of very few content it should stick to the bottom. So letting the content-holding div fill up using: min-height: calc(100%-footerHeight-headerHeight) of the height is the idea. If I use your solution I will have the footer floating over content whenever the content fills more than 100% screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use js to solve your problem.

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
var remainHeight = main.offsetHeight - content.offsetHeight - footer.offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('footer').style.marginTop = remainHeight + 'px';
```

The `#main` in `div` has `height: 100%`.
The `#content` in `div` has class `ng-view`.

You can write it in your controller also.

Comment: thanks I could use this as the dirty workaround however I would have to manipulate every page and that's not really the angular way to do it as of my understanding.